# Exclude certain Products from Magento sitemap.xml generation

Tags: php, magento, sitemap

I need to make sure a handful of Products are NOT inthe generated Sitemap.xml file in Magento.

Anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to generally disable the products to take them out of the sitemap, but still want them to be shown in the catalog and found per search but only hide them from the sitemap, you could override `Mage_Sitemap_Model_Resource_Catalog_Product::getCollection()` like this:

```
public function getCollection($storeId)
{
    $products = array();

    $store = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId);
    /* @var $store Mage_Core_Model_Store */

    if (!$store) {
        return false;
    }

    $urCondions = array(
        'e.entity_id=ur.product_id',
        'ur.category_id IS NULL',
        $this->_getWriteAdapter()->quoteInto('ur.store_id=?', $store->getId()),
        $this->_getWriteAdapter()->quoteInto('ur.is_system=?', 1),
    );
    $this->_select = $this->_getWriteAdapter()->select()
        ->from(array('e' => $this->getMainTable()), array($this->getIdFieldName()))
        ->join(
            array('w' => $this->getTable('catalog/product_website')),
            'e.entity_id=w.product_id',
            array()
        )
        ->where('w.website_id=?', $store->getWebsiteId())
        // --- exclude single product by its entity_id
        ->where('e.entity_id<>152')
        // --- exclude multiple products by their entity_id's
        // ->where('e.entity_id NOT IN (?)', array(152, 156))
        ->joinLeft(
            array('ur' => $this->getTable('core/url_rewrite')),
            join(' AND ', $urCondions),
            array('url' => 'request_path')
        );

    $this->_addFilter($storeId, 'visibility', Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInSiteIds(), 'in');
    $this->_addFilter($storeId, 'status', Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->getVisibleStatusIds(), 'in');

    $query = $this->_getWriteAdapter()->query($this->_select);
    while ($row = $query->fetch()) {
        $product = $this->_prepareProduct($row);
        $products[$product->getId()] = $product;
    }

    return $products;
}
```

Based on Magento CE 1.7.0.2 code, but afaik the principle is the same in all Magento versions.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.  Magento is really different architecture then anything I have seen before.  Now I need to actually enhance this, so the admin can select and option from the Product Meta tab to hide a product.  Then in this code i can pull in that value hopefully and build my list of ID's.  I will post a new question in regards to that though, thanks for your help thus far

Comment: How we can add condition for out of stock products. We only wants in stock product in the sitemap.xml

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to include certain product in sitemap.xml then disable those products

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own module, and change the behaviour of `Mage_Sitemap_Model_Sitemap::generateXml` to filter included products.